# kd-tree vs. cell lists

Tags: algorithm, simulation, computational-geometry

In molecular simulations people often use neighbor list algorithms (cell lists / Verlet table) to calculate the neighbor particles for each particle.

Then, running the simulation, each particle knows his neighbors at runtime.
The computational effort building such neighbor list scales linear with the number of particles (O(N)).

On the other hand kd-trees are often used to locate the nearest neighbors in a lot of applications. Building such a tree also scales linear with the number of particles.

So, whats better than? If the dimension is moderate 2/3D and the range of the
search will not change?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on application from a quick look at wiki's [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) and [cell list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_lists), the complexity to search, add/delete and compute interactions is different for each data structure and algorithm used, so depending on whether the number of particles can change dynamicaly or remain constant the efficiency will be different.

Furthernore k-d trees can be used in other applications or provide other features

> ..k-d trees are a useful data structure for several applications, such
>   as searches involving a multidimensional search key (e.g. range
>   searches and nearest neighbor searches). k-d trees are a special case
>   of binary space partitioning trees.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty, but "Building such a tree also scales linear with the number of particles", wouldn't it scale logarithmic?

Comment: @NickoPo, the [complexity of operations of k-d tress on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Complexity), it states that building a k-d-tree from n points takes on average O(nlog^2n) and Inserting a new point into a balanced k-d tree takes O(log n) time, so inserting k new points would scale linearly as O(klogn)

Comment: Perhaps, again i feel a bit rusty, but "scale linearly as O(klogn)" seems odd, since in this case n will grow by k. Meaning the tree is larger after each insertion.

Comment: @NickoPo, correct, the O(klogn) was kind of rough. i'm not going to do the complexity analysis right now (which might require non-trivial application of the master theorem), so i'll leave it there and refer to the wiki and links therein